# bwu_datagrid Polymer 1 : height 100% inside a div

Tags: dart, polymer, bwu-datagrid

I'm trying to create a custom polymer 1 component with a bwu_datagrid inside of it. This component can be resized on-demand, I've seen the "e11_autoheight" and "e12_fillbrowser" examples, but I don't want to rely on "100vh", nor force the parent div to grow to show ALL rows.

Is there a way to permit the datagrid to grow when a parent div is resized but continue to keep the scrollbar if the parent div is smaller than the # of rows?

Any guidance is highly appreciated.

Comment: Also, I thought about enclosing a bwu_datagrid with "autoHeight: true" inside a resizing div. This almost, almost accomplishes what I want, but then the right scrollbar scrolls everything, column headers and rows....I guess I'm looking for a "autoHeight: true" that doesn't strip the scroll capabilities from the viewport and it's capable of resizing the viewport accordingly... if this isn't possible with the current version, I'll have to figure something else, but I'm hoping the SO massive could help :)

Comment: I have to look it up myself (not yet on my computer). As far as I remember you have to call a method (`resize`?)on the BwuDatagrid when the size of the container changes. I'll check later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use for example

```
dom.window.onResize.listen((dom.Event e) => grid.resizeCanvas(e));
```

See https://github.com/bwu-dart/bwu_datagrid/blob/44215176ca3443d76b1a0573a25186e97ca7f207/example_/lib/e12_fillbrowser/app_element.dart#L86

There might be other reasons for the container to resize than a resized window , but there is no way to get resize events from elements (at least not from all browsers).

In this case you have to find other means to invoke this code. For example if you have a splitter component, you would get some drag events or similar.

Comment: Ahh, yes, that took care of it...but it raises some concerns as to what happens with multiple grids on the same view....all will get "resizeCanvas" callled...I'll have to test this for performance. I got pretty close by doing this css override, but I'm not a big fan of "!important" and my team fears anything with "calc"...

    :host::content #viewport {
        height: calc(100% - 26px) !important;
    }